# Show More Posts from Stream on FB Graph API FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to collect data from the stream of groups. Here is an example

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT post_id, app_data, type, actor_id, target_id, like_info, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = 1400366526844437&type=308&limit=1000&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

So if anybody try that above you will get results just fine but my problem is that it shows just a small amount of post when the page have far more post and is not giving me the option to for next page either. Is there a way to make it post more?

I already tried adding

```
limit=1000
```

But that doesn't worked any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution so here it is for people following behind

instead of the above syntax use this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT post_id, created_time , app_data, type, actor_id, target_id,comments, message FROM stream WHERE  source_id = <page or group id> limit 500&access_token=
```

as one can see instead of limit=500 after the type just place the limit 500 after the source id and that solves the issue.